# Can I use WITH in TSQL twice to filter a result set like my example?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I need to do something like this but SQL Server 2008 doesn't like it. My query is actually more complex than this and I realize this isn't the best way to accomplish what I'm doing but my focus is on the functionality of the WITH statement and not the select and where statements.

> WITH stuff1 AS (
>       select name, startdate, id from employees where startdate > 0 )
>
> WITH stuff2 AS (
>       select name, startdate, id from stuff1 )
>
> select * from stuff2 where id > 10

Comment: Theres no shame in using a temp table or table variable when you need one

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I do it all the time:

```
WITH stuff1 AS (
    SELECT name
           ,startdate
           ,id
    FROM employees
    WHERE startdate > 0
)
,stuff2 AS (
    SELECT name
           ,startdate
           ,id
    FROM stuff1
)
SELECT *
FROM stuff2
WHERE id > 10
```

As far as I can tell, I haven't reached a limit in CTEs.

The only thing you can't do (which would be pretty useful) is reuse CTEs in separate `SELECT`s:

```
WITH stuff1 AS (
    SELECT name
           ,startdate
           ,id
    FROM employees
    WHERE startdate > 0
)
,stuff2 AS (
    SELECT name
           ,startdate
           ,id
    FROM stuff1
)
SELECT *
FROM stuff2
WHERE id > 10
;
SELECT *
FROM stuff2
WHERE id < 10
```

Say.  Instead you have to copy and paste the entire CTE chain again.

Comment: does the above work without the ; terminator between the first and second selects?

Comment: No.  CTEs can only be used on a single operation.  INSERT/SELECT/DELETE whatever, but they are basically consumed at that point.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, very handy indeed and I definitely need it for some of my stored procedures.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to us a series of sub-queries.
Or sub-queries nested in a CTE.

An example of sub-queries using Northwind:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT * FROM dbo.Employees WHERE Country = 'USA') as TableFiltered1
     ) AS TableFilterd2 WHERE City = 'Seattle'
```

You can use two CTEs, but maybe not the way you wanted to, see:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml

Comment: In my experience, anything with subqueries can be transformed very quickly to use CTEs.  The reduced nesting level and ability to layer them very easily in declaration style and not repeating yourself makes a significant difference to readability and maintainability.

Comment: I agree. That's kind of why I included the link that showed an example of comma-separated CTE. I think its the 3rd or 4th example in the '4guys' link. I was trying to layout all the options.

Answer (score -3):

Nope, you can only have one CTE in a statement as I found out the other day.

*EDIT*: And that WITH statement is a Common Table Expression, very handy feature.

Comment: Actually, you can have multiple CTEs, and they can build on each other and even multiple CTEs within the CTE chain, separate with a comma - only one WITH statement can be used.

Comment: I hadn't realised they had to be comma-separated.  This will be handy.  I've been reading my SQL 2008 book and they mention CTE's, but they don't mention the use of multiple CTE's in one query, which is a shame.

Comment: Yep, I posted an example below.  I've been using it very heavily for the last year in a port from a 3GL system.